# Stata and R giving different results for zero-inflated negative binomial regression

Tags: r, regression, stata, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I know this has technically already been asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/587145/r-and-stata-show-different-results-when-i-run-zero-inflated-poisson-in-each-prog), but it doesn't look like the previous question had a reproducible example. I am having the same problem: Very simple, running a zero-inflated negative binomial model, and finding a different result across Stata and R. The difference is minor for the count model, but very different for the excess zero model, and I cannot explain why. The example data I am using is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11e63e6wGoP5h__Pwgj2e381MQ1HS1w3q/view?usp=sharing).

Here's what I'm running in R.

```
zeroinfl(count ~ X1 | X1, dist='negbin', data=d)
```

And here are the results.

```
Call:
zeroinfl(formula = count ~ X1 | X1, data = d, dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.1831 -0.1831 -0.1500 -0.1500 17.4408 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.7013     0.3330   2.106  0.03519 *  
X1            1.8353     0.5757   3.188  0.00143 ** 
Log(theta)   -3.3781     0.1933 -17.474  < 2e-16 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -7.922     54.678  -0.145    0.885
X1             7.220     54.628   0.132    0.895
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 0.0341 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 162 
Log-likelihood: -461.8 on 5 Df
```

Here's what I'm running in Stata.

```
zinb count X1, inflate(X1)
```

And here are the results.

```
Zero-inflated negative binomial regression              Number of obs =    540
Inflation model: logit                                  Nonzero obs   =     69
                                                        Zero obs      =    471
                                                        LR chi2(1)    =   9.23
Log likelihood = -461.8478                              Prob > chi2   = 0.0024

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       count | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
count        |
          X1 |   1.835959   .5757107     3.19   0.001     .7075868    2.964331
       _cons |    .700527   .3323622     2.11   0.035     .0491091    1.351945
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
inflate      |
          X1 |   15.77527   3927.949     0.00   0.997    -7682.863    7714.413
       _cons |  -16.47854   3927.949    -0.00   0.997    -7715.118    7682.161
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnalpha |   3.378581   .1922176    17.58   0.000     3.001841     3.75532
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       alpha |   29.32911   5.637573                      20.12255    42.74791
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, the count model coefficients are similar, but the zero-inflation model results are pretty different. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your variables the same type in both - e.g. factor in R, but numeric in Stata?

Comment: They're numeric in both, just checked with class() in R and codebook in Stata. (Also thank you for fixing that typo, oops.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that the two MLEs in the inflation model are $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, and it's just that Stata gets maybe one iteration closer to infinite before stopping.  The count model parameters, which are finite, are basically the same.

The sum of the two inflation-model parameters are -0.702 and -0.704, which is also good.  Theta in R is very close to 1/alpha in Stata.

That is, the agreement is pretty good, it's just that some of the MLEs are infinite and their standard errors are also infinite.

Comment: Thank you for this response, it is helpful and I think I do understand the spirit of what you are saying. My follow-up would be this: Since there's not complete separation in the data, I do not know why there would be this issue. I gather that a possible reason is because while the data seems overdispersed (and I have already checked that the fit for a NB model seems better than Poisson), the amount of zero-inflation is just so high that it is unable to estimate with a NB model. However, I don't know how to explain this for sure, any resources or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at the data ranges, and I think you'd get a better feel for what's going on by looking on the probability scale rather than the log odds scale.

Comment: I think this is the right thought, I am going to work through the predicted probabilities, thanks.